# Multiplication table bug in java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm a newbie and I wrote the following program to print 10 multiples of 1-9 number. But when I run the program, it starts from 5 X 4 = 20. I'm using BlueJ.

```
class MultiplicationTable
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int a=1;a<=9;a++)
        {
            for(int b=1;b<=10;b++)
            {
                System.out.println(a+" X "+b+" = "+(a*b));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does start from `1 X 1 = 1`. Perhaps you need to scroll up in the window where you're running this? Or the window doesn't have enough buffer to show all lines of the output?

Comment: It starts at 1 X 1 = 1, probably your number of output lines is limited?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how my buffer was limited before.

Answer (score 1):

It is buffer size problem.

1. Go to `Options`.
2. Then turn on `Unlimited Buffering`.

Hopefully it may solve your issue.

### From [BlueJ Environment Reference Manual](https://www.bluej.org/doc/bluej-ref-manual.pdf):

**Keep all output in terminal procedure:**

terminal window:

menu: `Options – Unlimited buffering`
shortcut: `—`

By default, the terminal buffers `only the last 48 lines of output`. If you want to
keep more of the output (for example to save it to a file later), switch on the
Unlimited buffering option from the terminal's Options menu.

With unlimited buffering, all output is kept in the terminal. This option can make
the output relatively slow if the application produces a lot of text.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the program and it works 
[image: It Works]

Answer (score 0):

Try printing with tabs and `print` instead `println` because that will print it in the new line.

```
        for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++) {
            for (int b = 1; b <= 10; b++) {
                System.out.print(a + " X " + b + " = " + (a * b) + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
         }
```